How do I stop vertex jumping when editing line features in QGIS with shapefiles?
I've been using QGIS 3.34 (previously 3.28) for editing shapefiles containing line features. However, I've encountered a persistent issue: occasionally, while editing a feature, a vertex from a completely different line (even those located far away) will inexplicably jump to the feature I'm currently editing. Alternatively, the vertex I intend to edit might suddenly relocate to a distant location.
Could anyone shed light on why this occurs and how I might resolve it?
I enabled snapping; but with a tolerance of 1 meter - the "jumping" goes 10 kilometers and more; with a lot of other objects between.

Feature while error - no vertices are shown. When I clicked on a vertex, another vertex jumped there (from an object I wasn't editing).

Feature while usual editing - vertices are there
I've saved the data as a geopackage now; so far it works without any problem.

Have you accidentally enabled snapping?

Do you have snapping activated ? If yes what tolerance ?

Sounds like you enabled snapping.

Yes, I enabled snapping; but with a tolerance of 1 meter - the "jumping" goes 10 kilometers and more; with a lot of other features between.

If your map units are in degrees then ypur "1 meter" is actually one degree (60nm)

Any time there is odd behavior I suggest checking the geometry of the layers involved.  In Snapping Advanced Configuration you can control what layers and what parts of them are snapped or made part of topological editing.
